# Locating a correct replacement for Honda Civic seat lever

Tags: parts, interior, seat

The lever that controls the inclination angle of the car seat in my Honda Civic 2001 EX broke. I have been trying to look for a replacement lever, but I can't seem to find one on Amazon. Do I need to figure out exactly what the name of the seat brand is in order to find the lever I need? How should I be searching for parts when I need them?

Comment: You are talking about the lever on the side which allows the seat to recline?

Comment: yes. I feel like it should be an easy replacement, but i'm not sure how to find the name of the seat that honda civics used in 2001. i was hoping that a google search of honda civic 2001 seat lever would work but i didn't get any hits

Comment: I'm betting you cannot get the part individually ... I'm thinking your best bet would be to go to a junk yard and pull one out. Easiest way I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part you are looking for is either called a [release lever](http://www.partswebsite.com/autopartspeople/?i=2&make=126&model=2146&year=2001&type=parts&act=new_subcategory_hp&section=126&catid=30183&subcatid=33760&fl_id=57) or a [recline knob](http://www.partswebsite.com/autopartspeople/?i=2&make=126&model=2146&year=2001&type=parts&act=new_subcategory_hp&section=126&catid=30183&subcatid=32423&fl_id=57) ... I don't know which, so you'll have to figure which one you need. You may want to call the company and figure out which one is correct for your needs.